# Custom Post Type conflicting with page?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a page on my website called Work (that uses a work.php page template) set up as my front page, where I would like to display a list of the last ten posts with the custom type called portfolio. Here is my code so far:

```
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <section id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'portfolio-post' ); ?>>
            <header>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <time datetime="<?php the_time('Y-m-d') ?>" pubdate><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></time>
            </header>
        </section>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

The problem is that nothing shows up on that page, despite my having created a couple of posts of this type in wordpress' backend. And when one is clicked, I would like to be taken to `/work/the_post_i_clicked/`. I must admit to being a bit confused here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the code where you register your portfolio post type and add/change this arguments:

```
'has_archive' => 'work', //under work you will see a list of portfolio items
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug' =>'work_item',
    'with_front' => false,
),
```

then manually go to Settings > Permalinks and refresh your permalink structure

after that your items will be listed under `/work` as an archive

and `work_item/name_of_post` as singles.

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you said:
- `/work/` is set up as my front page (just so you know) and when I visit this page, the last 10 custom posts still don't show up.
- when I click on "view post" in the backend, it works, I'm taked to the single-portfolio.php template with the name of the custom post and everything

Comment: well the you need to set the work page template if its your front page

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify. Still not sure what you mean...

Comment: You don't need a page for that ,So remove the page named `work` and rename your `work.php` theme file to `archive-portfolio.php` that is it.